# how does svn work with apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, development

i've got ubuntu installed with lamp.

im using webdav to upload/download files to/from the ubuntu web server, after i have edited the php source files in netbeans. however, i wonder what is best practice for editing source files and committing these changes to the new website.

cause if we are 2-3 developers, i guess we have to use svn. but i have never used it before so i wonder how it works.

should i install it and then select the /var/www (apaches webroot) as the repository folder? then when i check in, all the changes will apply immediately?

could someone please explain following steps: how to download, edit the source files, upload the files and see the new changes in the website.

cause i have only worked with a local apache before, and it was only me. now there will be some more programmers so i have to set up a decent, central environment for this, and have to know how netbeans, svn, webdav and apache works all together.

thanks!

Comment: This is really a question for Stack Overflow. Setting up SVN is our area, using it is theirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I do, in case this helps. I create an SVN repo for every project on the server, under a domain specifically for SVN (svn.mycompany.com). I check the repo out to my machine (and all other developers working on the project do the same). When I make changes, I commit them from my local machine to the repo on the server. For the public website (`/var/www` from your question) I check out a copy of the source code *the same as I would for my local development machine*. Then, I have a subversion "commit hook" on the server which runs `svn update` on the remote website. So the procedure for making changes looks like:

1. Use `svn checkout` (if this is the first time) or `svn update` or NetBeans to check out/update to the latest source code to the developer's local machine.
2. Make some changes
3. use `svn commit` or NetBeans to commit the changes (includig a commit message detailing what changed and why, of coure)
4. The changes are committed to the SVN repo on the server and the server runs `svn update` to apply my changes to the actual website.
5. Test changes on the website, if more work needs to be done, repeat.

The only thing I would add is, I have my SVN hook update a staging site. When the client approved the sgaging site I can use subversion to update the live site.

Comment: thanks. this is exactly what i needed to know! one thing..so the svn respository is a folder for each project and its files. and then we got the /var/www (apache's webroot) folder. when you check in the files, you got a "commit hook" that senses this, and perform a "svn update" so that the /var/www get the latest versions in the svn repository? one more question, what exactly is your "commit hook"? cause maybe i should have one too?

Comment: Yes, that's about right. I'll post the SVN commit hook script tomorrow.